# Calling onTouchEvent from function

Tags: java, android, touch-event, strategy-pattern

I have a onTouchEvent just in my class and it works good. I am using it for the movement of some objects. Now I want to use a strategy pattern to be able to have different strategies of the movement of objects.
I am creating an interface

```
public interface ControlBehavior {

    public void control();

}
```

Then, I want to use onTouchEvent in the function "control".

```
public class TouchControl implements ControlBehavior {
    public void control(){
        //How to use it here?
    }
}
```

Finally, It should work like this:

```
public MyClass{
    private ControlBehavior controlBehavior;
    ...
    public MyClass(){
        controlBehavior = new TouchControl();
    }
    ...
    public void control(){
        controlBehavior.control();
    }
}
```

Comment: are you looking for `View.dispatchTouchEvent` method? You can create MotionEvent instances and pas them to dispatchTouchEvent